# Detect spoofed Caller-id on Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am trying to find out if there is an easy way to detect whether an incoming call is coming from a spoofed caller-id. Does anyone know of a good way to do this with the current API?

Comment: This is not a research service. The best way to get help is do some research and post back why it doesn't full fill your requirements. Please try and add what you've tried and what results you have too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible within the [voice API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).

There are [SIP headers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/sip-parameters/sip-parameters.xhtml#sip-parameters-2) called `P-Asserted-Identity` that under certain circumstances can show this and `Diversion` can tell you if a number has been fowarded, etc., but they are not always included/supported or accurate.